# Is anyone now writing philosophy in the style of Plato - the Dialogue?

Tags: plato, continental-philosophy, analytic-philosophy, hume

Hume wrote some of his works in the style of a Dialogue following Platos lead; has any-one since? Or is it all prose?

Comment: Any number of people have written philosophical dialogues, the real question is who has paid attention?

Comment: @sunami: sure; it appears as a moribund literary tradition; but for all one knows there may be some gems out there; GB Shaw explicitly dramatised Nietzsche in *Man & Superman*.

Comment: You may be interested in Alain Badiou's "hypertranslation" of the Republic (which introduces additional characters among other things...)

Comment: Bishop Berkeley and St. Anselm both wrote noted philosophical dialogues, but both were prior to Hume.  @MoziburUllah My prior comment, for what it's worth, was more rueful than mocking.  I myself wrote a book of philosophy in dialog form --but it vanished silently without a trace.

Comment: @sunami:ok; its sometimes hard to judge online...

Comment: The teachings of the Hindu saint Ramakrishna (1836-1886) are recorded in "The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna" in a similar manner by his disciple who went by the name 'M'.

Comment: Don't know if he counts as a philosopher, but Hofstadter wrote in dialogue from a lot . I think it takes away from his writing, as his subject matter is best suited for the analytic style, and the dialogue from makes it confusing.

Comment: Would books that consist of dialogue between existing people also count? I don't mean simple interview books (of which I know several) or transcripts of debates at conferences.

Answer (score 4):

See John Perry's *A Dialogue on Personal Identity* and his *Dialogue on Good, Evil and the Existence of God*. Furthermore some of David Lewis's smaller pieces (written together with Stephanie Lewis) are dialogues: 'Holes' and a review of Casati and Varzi's *Holes and Other Superficialities*

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few examples of books using the dialogue form:

- [*Worlds Apart:  A Dialogue of the 1960's*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Barfield#Worlds_Apart) by Owen Barfield (1963) is written in the form of a fictional dialogue.
- [*Corydon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corydon_%28book%29) by André Gide (1911) contains four Socratic dialogues on homosexuality.
- [Peter Kreeft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Kreeft) published several books that are fictional dialogues between Socrates and a more recent philosopher, e.g. *Socrates Meets Hume*, *Socrates Meets Kant*, *Socrates Meets Machiavelli*.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have survived more in logic and foundations than philosophy broadly.

Lakatos *Proofs and Refutations* on the philosophy of science as applied to mathematics is not so out-of-date.  Neither are various books like *Surreal Numbers* by Knuth, or some of Raymond Smulliyan.  Large parts of Douglas Hoffstadter's *Godel, Escher, Bach* are in dialog form.

I think the form is coming to be restricted to popularizations or restatements of work that is kind of impenetrable otherwise.

Comment: I would have guessed along the same lines; I'd add in Lewis Carolls *Alice in Wonderland* for its playful use of language and logic - Deleuze I think wrote an essay on it.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew Stewart did a little bit in his book: The Truth About Everything: An Irreverent History of Philosophy.